# Custom delegate method doesn't get called

Tags: ios, objective-c

So, I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20257863/2526007) answer in trying to pass data between two classes in an iOS project without storyboards. I'm trying to abstract all my server calls in a different class, so the ViewControllers don't get too cramped. I have an OfferRequest class, which handles the server requests and declares the protocol:

```
@protocol OfferRequestDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)addOfferRequest: (OfferRequest *)request dataFromRequest: (NSMutableArray *)data;

@end

@interface OfferRequest : NSObject <LocationManagerDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <OfferRequestDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

The idea is to call `addOfferRequest: dataFromRequest` in `connectionDidFinishLoading`, set the data as the result from the request and pass it on to the ViewController.

**In OfferRequest.m:**

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSMutableArray *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    [self.delegate addOfferRequest:self dataFromRequest:result];

}
```

I declare my ViewController as a delegate for the OfferRequest:

```
@interface CategorySuggestionViewController : UIViewController <OfferRequestDelegate>
```

Initialize the OfferRequest object and set it's delegate:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    offer = [OfferRequest new];
    offer.delegate = self;
}
```

And then implement the delegate method:

```
-(void)addOfferRequest:(OfferRequest *)request dataFromRequest:(NSMutableArray *)data {
    NSLog(@"received data = %@", data);
}
```

But it never gets called. What am I missing ?

Comment: Does your connectionDidFinishLoading method get called?

Comment: Could you paste the code with the the creation of connection and the request for that connection? -Off topic- Maybe you should consider using blocks.

Comment: Yes, it gets called and the data is correctly set.

Comment: @AdiPop I don't think it is relevant, since the data in OfferRequest is correctly set. Also: could you please point me to an explanation how to use blocks in this situation ? I'm not very experienced with objective c.

Comment: Did you check inside connectionDidFinishLoading if delegate is not nil ?

Comment: @AdiPop Hm, yes, it is nil. I have `@synthesize delegate;` at the beginning of `OfferRequset.m` and I thought it gets initialized there. How and where should I initialize it ?

Comment: @smeshko Are you allocating offer in any other place apart from viewDidLoad?

Comment: @thavasidurai No, `offer` is a property that I use throughout the ViewController, I don't need any other `OfferRequest` instances. The weird thing is, I call the `OfferRequest` method in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and set the delegate in `viewDidLoad`, so you'd expect, that the delegate is set before it is needed in `OfferRequest`. Or am I seeing it wrong ?

Comment: initiliaze your  offer =[[OfferRequest alloc]init]; instead of  offer = [OfferRequest new]

Comment: @karthikeyan Still doesn't work: `delegate` is still Nil in `connectionDidFinishLoading` and the delegate method doesn't get called.

Comment: @smeshko if possible can you please post code which you wrote in didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: if connectionDidFinishLoading get called,check your result array whether having value or not

Comment: I think that the instance of CategorySuggestionViewController is deallocated that will explain that the delegate is nil.

Comment: In how many different places do you create an OfferRequest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I don't know where the problem exactly was, but what I did to fix it, was to create a new init method, where I pass the delegate:

```
-(instancetype)initWithDelegate: (id<OfferRequestDelegate>) delegate {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.delegate = delegate;
    }

    return self;
}
```

So I initialize the OfferRequest object in the VC and pass self and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

**your OfferRequest class** like below i have given name it as connectionClass

**connectionClass.h**

```
@protocol connectionDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)connectionSucceed:(NSData *)data;
-(void)connectionFailed:(NSError *)error;
@end

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface connectionClass : NSObject
{
    id<connectionDelegate> delegate;
    NSMutableData *receivedData;
    NSString *encodedString;
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest;
    NSURL *url;
    NSString *length;
    NSURLConnection *Connect;

}
@property(nonatomic, retain) id<connectionDelegate> delegate;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *receivedData;
- (void)connectionWithURL:(NSString *)URL;
@end
```

**connectionClass.m**

```
#import "connectionClass.h"

@implementation connectionClass
@synthesize delegate, receivedData;
- (void)connectionWithURL:(NSString *)URL
{
    url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[self urlencode:URL]];
    theRequest= [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
    [theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    length = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[URL length]];
    [theRequest setValue:length forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[URL dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    Connect = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if (Connect)
    {
        self.receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
    }
    else
    {
        NSError *error;
        [self.delegate connectionFailed:error];
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [self.receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [self.delegate connectionSucceed:self.receivedData];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [self.delegate connectionFailed:error];
}
-(NSString *) urlencode: (NSString *) string
{
    encodedString = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)string, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"", kCFStringEncodingUTF16));
    return encodedString;
}


@end
```

don't forget to import your connectionclass and delegate

```
@interface yourclass : UIViewController<connectionDelegate>
```

**Initialize the OfferRequest object and set it's delegate:**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    connection = [[connectionClass alloc]init];
    connection.delegate = self;
     [connection connectionWithURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pass your url here"]];
}
```

The delegate method will have your values

```
-(void)connectionSucceed:(NSData *)data
{
    NSError *error;
    self.dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
    //nslog your data
}

//Connection failure
-(void)connectionFailed:(NSError *)error
{
  //handle error message
}
```

Comment: you set retain for connectionDelegate it is not better practice it should be weak

Comment: @thavasidurai thanks for your suggestion.But it will retain a value,when using multiple connection so i used retain property

Answer (score -2):

I guess delegate should be a pointer object and not the object.

It may be help you

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSObject <OfferRequestDelegate> *delegate;
```

and make should your delegate is been set, i.e. make sure your code below is getting called.

```
 [self.delegate addOfferRequest:self dataFromRequest:result];
```